# Prove that there is an $a,b\in{\mathbb{R}}$ with $a<b$ and $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>5$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there is an $a,b\in{\mathbb{R}}$ with $a<b$ and $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>5$.

Given is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by, $f(x)=x^{13}+\frac{31}{2+\sin(x)}$

I know I have to use the intermediate value theorem but I don't know how. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: $a=-10,b=10$? No IVT involved...

Comment: The first term is decreasing for negative values and increasing for positive ones with no bound. The second term is never smaller than $31/(2+1)=31/3=10.333\dots$ and never bigger than $31/(2-1)=31/1=31$. So for sufficiently small a and sufficiently large b this will definitely be true.